# How to split the values of a column to differenet columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the below format. I want to split the values of **points** column into different columns like A,B,C and so on based on the number of items in the list by deleting the original column.

```
df:
         x           y              points
    0   82.123610   16.724781   [1075038212.0, -18.099967840282456, -18.158378...
    1   82.126540   16.490998   [1071765909.0, -20.406018294234215, -15.850444...
    2   82.369578   17.402203   [1072646747.0, -16.839004016179505, -18.334996...
    3   81.612240   17.464167   [1096294130.0, -15.335239025421126, -15.303402...
```

Comment: Naming from A, B, C, ... and so on and what name should 27th column get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: @StasBuzuluk No, It is creating new columns keeping the original column. I'm looking for a simplified solution by dropping the column and creating new columns at one stretch

Answer (score 1):

I think best here is create numeric columns names:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('points').tolist(), index=df.index))
```

If length of list is less like 27 is possible use:

```
import string

d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase))

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('points').tolist(), index=df.index).rename(columns=d))
```